# Is there any way to search in the current narrowed subtree in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, search

I can use `C-x n s (org-narrow-to-subtree)` to narrow the content to the current subtree, which is great. After doing that, I want to search a keyword in the current narrowed subtree(instead of the whole file). I tried opening `org-agenda`, and use the search functionality(`s`) in it. But it didn't work as expected. Org Mode searched the whole file for my keyword.

So my question is, how to only search in the current narrowed subtree?

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of special `org`-specific search feature?  Because the normal isearch (`C-s`) or occur (`M-s o`) etc will work just fine in a narrowed buffer.

Comment: @phils Yes, I'm talking about the search feature in `org-mode`. `C-s` isn't enough for me because I want to search the narrowed buffer but only show the result as an org heading list, `C-s` cannot do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `C-c a` brings up the agenda dispatcher, you can restrict the agenda search by saying `C-c a < s` in the narrowed buffer. The [dispatcher documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Dispatcher.html#Agenda-Dispatcher) says:

> ‘<’
> Restrict an agenda command to the current buffer.  If narrowing
> is in effect restrict to the narrowed part of the buffer.  After
> pressing ‘<’, you still need to press the character selecting the
> command.

Comment: Thanks, it worked just as expected! Except that when the search result is shown, I was kicked out of the narrowed buffer. It would be better if I can remain in the narrowed buffer. That said, it's good enough since going into the narrowed buffer again isn't a hard thing.